# Retrieve user details after providing the primary key in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

ImproperlyConfigured at `/api/account/profile/36` Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "account-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.

### views.py

```
@api_view(['GET', ])
def retrieve_user_account_view(self, pk):
    user_account = query_db(pk)
    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    request = factory.get('/')
    serializer = AccountSerializer(instance=user_account, context={'request': 
        Request(request)})
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
```

### serializers.py

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'full_name', 'email', 'password', 
                  'confirm_password',
                  'date_created', 'last_updated', 'phone_number', 'status')
        extra_kwargs = {
                  'password': {'write_only': True}
        }
```

### models.py

```
class Account(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=12, auto_created=True, 
        default='ACTIVE')
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(region='NG')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_created']
```

### urls.py

```
from account.api.views import(
    user_account_registration_view,
    retrieve_user_account_view,
    update_user_account_view,
    delete_user_account_view,
)

app_name = "account"

urlpatterns = [
    path('register', user_account_registration_view, name="register"),
    path('profile/<int:pk>', retrieve_user_account_view, name="retrieve"),
    path('profile/update/<int:pk>', update_user_account_view, name="update"),
    path('profile/delete/<int:pk>', delete_user_account_view, name="delete"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the second path from

```
path('profile/<int:pk>', retrieve_user_account_view, name="retrieve"),
```

to

```
path('profile/<int:pk>', retrieve_user_account_view, name="account-detail"),
```

Or just pass the `view_name` via `extra_args` in your `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`

[How hyperlinked views are determined](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#how-hyperlinked-views-are-determined)

Comment: Thanks Mohammed Jafari. I have been able to resolve the issue.